# cant git push heroku master - buildpacks

Tags: heroku, github, hubot, campfire

well simply this is what i am getting;

```
 sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:/opt/hubot/bin$ heroku buildpacks
 === young-everglades-12415 Buildpack URL
 heroku/java
 sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:/opt/hubot/bin$ sudo git push heroku master
 Counting objects: 3, done.
 Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
 Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
 Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 2.14 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
 Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
 remote: Compressing source files... done.
 remote: Building source:
 remote: 
 remote: -----> Failed to detect set buildpack https://codon-        buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/java.tgz
 remote: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure 
 remote: 
 remote:  !     Push failed
 remote: Verifying deploy...
 remote: 
 remote: !  Push rejected to young-everglades-12415.
 remote: 
 To https://git.heroku.com/young-everglades-12415.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/young-           everglades-12415.git'
 sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:/opt/hubot/bin$
```

although i did set a buildpack on the app git push failed because no buildpack detected ?

How can i resolve this, and is it actually the right steps towards deploying hubot ?

Answer (score 1):

The heroku build packs still use the [detection script](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-api#bin-detect) to identify the language in use. Since Hubot is not a java project and it looks like you are using the java build pack, I suspect the detection script failed.

To fix this, try removing the buildpack.

```
% heroku buildpacks:remove heroku/java
```

After this I would try,

```
% git push heroku master
```

(Optional) I believe the `rediscloud` addon is needed for some scripts. You can add it with,

```
% heroku addons:create rediscloud
```

Then watch the logs `heroku logs` and see what happens.

There is a good deployment guide in [hubot/deploying/heroku.md](https://github.com/github/hubot/blob/master/docs/deploying/heroku.md)

Comment: as you suggested i did remove the buildpacks, and tried to create rediscloud but unfortunately i am facing another dilemma which is verification. everytime i try to use the command to create reidcloud or even from the browser heroku dash bord addons i get the request to verify my account with a credit card ? is there a way around this ?

Comment: Sorry, not that I know of. Maybe skip that step and see if you can get it deployed without it?

Comment: Still getting the same error no default lang. detected ?

Comment: all right, well i solved the git push heroku master by adding redis addon with command heroku buildpacks:add -i 1 https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-redis.git and then git push heroku master. Now what is the next step to interact with hubot >?